# How convert a String in &str in Impl block in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm very new to Rust and to get more familiar with the language I started to write a little ToDo program.

I've made a Struct corresponding to a Task :

```
    struct Task {
        id: int,
        title: &'static str
    }
```

And I tried to implement some methods to get directly the formatted line to write in a file :

```
    impl Task {
        fn to_string (&self) -> String {
            let line = self.id.to_string() + "\t" + self.title;
            line
        }

        fn to_str (&self) -> &str {
            let line = self.to_string();
            let formatted_str : &str = line.as_slice();
            formatted_str
        }
    }
```

I get an error which says that 'line' does not live long enough. I've tried to add the lifetime information as it is explained here : http://rustbyexample.com/lifetime/fn.html but I've got the same error again.

Is there a solution to this situation ? I'm new to Rust so I probably missed something.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fundamentally not possible. If you return a reference to something, that something must be stored somewhere. Ignoring task-local storage and statics, that means for a method that takes just `&self` that it must be stored in `self`.

You cannot return a reference to something that is owned by the method you are returning it from, for when you return the reference to it, it passes out of scope and is destroyed.

Let your caller call `self.to_string().as_slice()` themselves if they need a string slice rather than an owned string.

---

Incidentally, for best results you should be implementing `std::fmt::Show`;

```
use std::fmt;

impl fmt::Show for Task {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{}\t{}", self.id, self.title)
    }
}
```

That gets you a [`.to_string()` method](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/master/std/to_str/trait.ToString.html) automatically, and you can use your `Task` directly in `format!("{}", task)` and so forth.

Answer (score 3):

If we look at the [rust documentation for `str`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/), we find a couple of insightful excerpts.

> &str is the borrowed string type. This type of string can only be created from other strings, unless it is a static string

and

> The actual representation of strings have direct mappings to vectors: &str is the same as &[u8].

This means that a non-static `&str` is represented as a pointer into the data owned by a vector of `u8`'s (i.e. a `String`). The `&str` itself, however, does not own the `u8`'s.

`line`, in your code above, is a local variable in the `to_str` function. This means that when `to_str` returns, `line` goes out of scope, and it destroys the data it owns: a bunch of `u8`'s. `formatted_str` is borrowing the data owned by `line`. Thus, you cannot return `formatted_str` because the lifetime of the data it is borrowing ends when `to_str` returns. You may find this clearer in [a simplified version of the code you provided](http://is.gd/3NvXuV).

I'm not experienced enough with rust myself to provide a solution to your problem, but hopefully this explains the error.